# Fail2ban doesn't find log file when launched from SYSTEMCTL but does when launched from CLI

Tags: fail2ban

### The problem

*Fail2ban **can't find the log file used by a jail** when launched with `systemctl start fail2ban.service` but works perfeclty when launched manually with `fail2ban-client start`.*

### The stacktrace

```
$ systemctl start fail2ban.service
$ systemctl status fail2ban.service

● fail2ban.service - Fail2Ban Service
  Process: 25113 ExecStart=/usr/bin/fail2ban-server -xf --logtarget=sysout start (code=exited, status=255)
  Process: 25112 ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /run/fail2ban (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

[25113]: ERROR   Failed during configuration: Have not found any log file for xxxxxx jail
[25113]: ERROR   Async configuration of server failed

Oct 02 10:37:56 gateway-tmp systemd[1]: fail2ban.service failed.
```

### Configuration

**My systemctl service :**

```
[Unit]
Description=Fail2Ban Service
After=network.target iptables.service firewalld.service ip6tables.service ipset.service nftables.service
PartOf=firewalld.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /run/fail2ban
ExecStart=/usr/bin/fail2ban-server -xf start
ExecStop=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client stop
ExecReload=/usr/bin/fail2ban-client reload
PIDFile=/run/fail2ban/fail2ban.pid
Restart=on-failure
RestartPreventExitStatus=0 255

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

FYI the start command above (`/usr/bin/fail2ban-server -xf start`) works as expected when launched manualy.

**My jail config :**

```
[xxxxxxxx]
enabled = true
port = http,https
filter = xxxxxxx
logpath = /path/to/log/file/data/log/*error.log
maxretry = 6
banaction = xxxxxx
```

FYI the file exists

### Env

Centos7
Fail2Ban v0.11.1

Comment: Checked SELinux?

Comment: @tetech `getenforce` returns `Enforcing`. Do you think that SELinux might block the access to the log file when launched by sysctl only ?

Comment: @tetech Woow I did `sudo setenforce 0` and fail2ban started to work again... Thx ! Do you have any idears of why SELinux impacts systemctl this way and what are the right SELinux values to set ? Anyway, if you make an answer I'll accept it as resolved.

Comment: Well... It seems to be a bug https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/171735/316670

Answer (score 1):

The SELinux context of logfiles can sometimes make a difference when running via systemctl.  The first thing to try is `sudo setenfore 0` and test.

If this fixes the problem, you might want to re-enable selinux (`sudo setenforce 1`) and add the appropriate permissions in SELinux.  Start by running `sudo audit2allow -a`, it should show what was being blocked by SELinux.  In brief,

```
audit2allow -a > local.te
checkmodule -M -m -o local.mod local.te
semodule_package -o local.pp -m local.mod
semodule -i ./local.pp
```

Take a look at `local.te` after the first step to make sure it is sane rather than blindly copy-pasting.  The second line is a validation check, the third packages up the rules into a module and the last actually loads them into SELinux.

Normally, installing a package like `fail2ban` also makes the appropriate SELinux adjustments, but sometimes not properly.

Comment: The second line (validation) fails with the error `local.te:4:ERROR 'Building a policy module, but no module specification found.' at token 'allow' on line 4:`. The *local.te* seems to be formated correctly but I'm not an expert on this matter.

Comment: Seems a `checkmodule` issue with some versions, https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1367748.  Maybe try using the `make` command suggested there instead?  You're encountering every possible difficulty!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this! First question I saw that pointed towards selinux as a culprit.  I couldn't find any logging that said selinux was preventing it, but it's in Enforcing mode and running `fail2ban-client start` did start the jails successfully, so this looks like it was my problem too.

As a bit of an selinux dummy, I didn't want to get into `local.pp` shennanigans as @tater suggest.  I think I've fixed this by changing the context of my logs directory to `http_log_t` manually.  These were previously `httpd_sys_content_t`.

I have my virtual host's files all under `/var/www/html/mydomain.com`, which contains `public_html` and `logs`.  I'd accidentally tagged the logs directory as `httpd_sys_content_t`, so this command resets the selinux settings for it:

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_log_t '/var/www/html/mydomain.com/logs(/.*)?'
# restorecon -Rv /var/www/html/mydomain.com
```

(this matches the directory, and all files in it)  `ls` then shows the `httpd_log_t` context for the log file that fail2ban has been told to monitor:

```
# ls -lZ /var/www/html/mydomain.com/logs/error.log
```

-rw-rw-rw-. root root system_u:object_r:httpd_log_t:s0 /var/www/html/mydomain.com/logs/error.log

Now fail2ban starts from `systemctl restart fail2ban` as well as the command line `fail2ban-client start`.